# Built-in transitions for StackView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Is there some predefined transition animations for `StackView` in QML and is there a way to set them for a `StackView` instance?

Looking at the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html#transitions), I can see ways to define custom `Transition`s but not how to choose one from the built-in already implemented.

Comment: AFAIK there are none.

Comment: There aren't really "built in" transitions you can chose from, there are default transitions you can override if you so chose.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmations. I ended up writing a custom transition.

Comment: Can someone answer this then? :)